Etf ethereum shows no value
etf ethereum shows verified swap but not showing trade activity or dollar value in
coinbase wallet. Etherscan shows verified transaction.

What is etf ethereum? Please include the hash of the transaction. Wallet applications generally won't show incoming transfers, and if it is a token and you haven't added the address it may not show value. Depending on network tracking or wallet application settings it may not show a dollar value.
